# binding dojo.grid to restful service with authentication via jsonreststore

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I searched a while for this issue, but could not find much about it.

In my javascript application I try to visualize data of my restful backend via jsonreststore and dgrid.

That is what I got so far:

```
    <script>
        function getRequest(args) {
            return {
                url: 'http://myworkingapiwithevents/events',
                handleAs: 'json',
                sync: false,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic HriB5jsHUib2K='
                }
            }
        }

        require(["dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/rpc/JsonService"], function (JsonRest, JsonService) {            
            service = new JsonService('http://myworkingapiwithevents/events', true /*isJson*/, undefined /*schema*/, getRequest);
            myStore = new JsonRest({ service: service });
        });

        require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (DataGrid, ObjectStore) {
            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }),
                structure: [
                    { name: "Event", field: "name", width: "200px" }
                ]
            }, "grid3");
            grid.startup();
        });
    </script>
```

For the beginning I use a hardcoded base64 authorization which should work for my backend service. With the getRequest method I initialize my service "workaround" with which my jsonreststore can handle the authorization.

In firebug (Chrome) I get the following errors:

```
ErrorCtor {stack: "Error: Unable to load http://myworkingapiwithevents/ev... p://localhost:52894/Scripts/dojo/dojo.js:1094:43)", message: "Unable to load http://myworkingapiwithevents/events status: 0", response: Object, status: 0, responseText: ""…}

Error {popStackFrame: function} "Error: Unable to load SMD from http://myworkingapiwithevents/events
```

Could it be some cross domain issue? I know that my backendservice supports cross domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use dojo/rpc/JsonService. Try this instead :

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/domReady!"], function (JsonRest, DataGrid, ObjectStore) {
        var restStore = new JsonRest({
            target : 'http://myworkingapiwithevents/events',
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic HriB5jsHUib2K='}
        });
        var dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore : restStore });
        grid = new DataGrid({
            store: dataStore,
            structure: [
                { name: "Event", field: "name", width: "200px" }
            ]
        }, "grid3");
        grid.startup();
});
```